# What is the Fourier Transform of $\operatorname{sgn}(t) \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(t)$?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, integration

I am wondering what the Fourier Transform of $\operatorname{sgn}(t) \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(t)$ will be, where $\operatorname{sgn}(t)$ indicates the signum function. It would seem obvious that this is equal to the FT of $1$, but I would like to see if this would be possible to find using the multiplicative property of the FT.

When I try this myself, I get stuck at trying to find the following integral:

$$\text{P.V.} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi q(q - \Omega)}\text{d}q$$

While this function is obviously equal to $0$ if $\Omega \neq 0$, the integral will diverge if $\Omega = 0$. Does this mean that we approach $0$, or is there a possibility that we approach the delta function? The former would make most sense to me but I have no idea how we could show this. Perhaps this is a better question for the math SE?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What ***is*** the Fourier Transform of $x(t)=1 \quad \forall t$?  Settle that first.

Comment: Find the Fourier Transform of the unit step function. Write signum in terms of the unit step function. Use linearity to find its Fourier Transform. Convolve it with itself!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson that should be equal to $2\pi \delta(\Omega)$, which means we expect the same result in the frequency domain if we only change a single point in time to a non-finite value and immediately take the transform, right?

Comment: @AhsanYousaf thanks for the reply, if I try this I still end up with the same integral besides some scaling and additional terms which can be found more easily.

Comment: What does the $P.V.$ in front of the integral mean?  If it's there by mistake, please _edit your question_ to correct it.

Comment: @TimWescott it is supposed to represent the Cauchy principal value of the integral considering there are singularities on the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions $f(t)=[\textrm{sgn}(t)]^2$ and $g(t)=1$ differ only at a single point $t=0$ ($f(0)=0$ whereas $g(0)=1$). The difference $f(t)-g(t)$ is sometimes referred to as [null function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NullFunction.html). The integral over a null function vanishes, and, consequently, $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ have the same Fourier transform (see [Lerch's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchsTheorem.html)).

Clearly, the Fourier transform of $g(t)$ (and hence of $f(t)$) equals $2\pi\delta(\omega)$. Of course, it must be possible to show this using the multiplication/convolution theorem. We have

$$\mathscr{F}\{\textrm{sgn}(t)\}=\frac{2}{j\omega}\tag{1}$$

(whereby it's understood that all integrals involving this correspondence are to be interpreted as principal values).

Consequently, we should expect

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{4}{\Omega (\Omega-\omega)}d\Omega=2\pi\delta(\omega)\tag{2}$$

One way to show this is via the definition of the Hilbert transform. We know that

$$\mathscr{H}\big\{\mathscr{H}\{f(x)\}\big\}=-f(x)\tag{3}$$

We also know that

$$\mathscr{H}\big\{\delta(x)\big\}=\frac{1}{\pi x}\tag{4}$$

Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$ results in

$$\delta(x) = -\mathscr{H}\left\{\frac{1}{\pi x}\right\}=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y(y-x)}dy\tag{5}$$

which is equivalent to $(2)$.

Comment: *//"Since $\textrm{sgn}(t)\cdot\textrm{sgn}(t)=1$,"//* uhm, not quite.  *//" its Fourier transform must equal $2\pi\delta(\omega)$."//* yah, but you need to dot your t's and cross your i's, Matt.

Comment: Not sure, but isn't $\text{sgn}(0) = 0$ and hence $\text{sgn}(t) \cdot \text{sgn}(t) = 1, t \ne 0$. So there is a discontinuity at $t = 0$. Does that change anything ?

Comment: @Hilmar it's infinitely thin and not a dirac delta.  So what does ***that*** change in an integral?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I have no idea, that's why I'm asking :-) :-) :-)

Comment: My first guess would be that the discontinuity it has a finite amplitude but infinitely small length, i.e. it has zero energy and so it would actually make no meaningful difference. We could define am error signal $\Delta(t) = -1, t = 0, 0 \;\text{else}$ and try to calculate it's Fourier Transform.  I'm guessing that would come out to 0, but I'm not sure I can do the formal math.

Comment: *//"The discontinuity has measure zero, so we can safely ignore it."//*  That's what I meant by "infinitely thin".  *//"So I believe the equality in my first sentence is justified. "//* No, Matt, you can't do that!  I'm disappointed.

Comment: $$\textrm{sgn}(t)\cdot\textrm{sgn}(t) \bigg|_{t=0} = 0$$  It shure the fuck doesn't equal 1.

Comment: @Hilmar RBJ, in the end we're free as hell to define $\operatorname{sgn}$ as we want; including unambigously setting $\operatorname{sgn}(0) = 1$. It doesn't really change the integral, anyways.

Comment: I actually do not believe we can get away with redefining $\operatorname{sgn}(\cdot)$.  But we maybe can get away with redefining the unit step at 0.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct by also considering the points made in the discussion here, thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Matt, I'm bitching about redefining a well-established mathematical function.  Never contradicted you about the integral.  I agree completely.  But we must not redefine $\operatorname{sgn}(\cdot)$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: That's a misunderstanding. I didn't intend to redefine the signum function, because there's no need to do so. The "=" sign means equal to almost everywhere, except for a single point ($t=0$). I added this in parentheses for complete clarity. For the Fourier transform, that single point difference is irrelevant, as we all agree on.

Comment: The "=" sign does ***not*** mean almost everywhere.  It simply means equality.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: That's right. I referred to the first sentence in my answer, including the qualifier "except at a single point ...". Mathematicians sometimes use "$\ldots =\ldots \textrm{ a.e.}$" for "almost everywhere".

Comment: I've rewritten the first part of my answer, hoping that everything is crystal clear now ...